# Using or in bind and validation?

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm using go gin with validation package called `ozzo-validation` and when I bind json data and validation error like this:

```
    err := c.ShouldBind(&user)

    valErrors := user.LoginValidate()

    if err != nil || valErrors != nil {
        util.ErrorJSON(c, http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
        return
    }
```

I got errors in console:

```
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2878 +0x43b
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0002cebe0, {0x17430c0, 0xc0004a6f30})
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1929 +0xb08
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:3033 +0x4e8
```

when I convert the above code to the following it works!

```
    var user models.User

    // Decode request data
    if err := c.ShouldBind(&user); err != nil {
        util.ErrorJSON(c, http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
        return
    }

    // Validate Error
    if err := user.LoginValidate(); err != nil {
        util.ErrorJSON(c, http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
        return
    }
```

Comment: The error message is ambiguous. And, how do you declare the user variable in the first code?

Comment: @Trock same in the second: it's model

Answer (score 0):

what is variable user? is it a model? why don't you declare validation on your model with validatin-ozzo like :

```
func (f *user) Validate() error {
    if err := validation.Validate(f.name, validation.Required); err != nil {
        return &response.ErrorResponse{
            ErrorID: 422,
            Msg: map[string]string{
                "en": "name cannot be empty",
            },
        }
    }
    return nil
}

type ErrorResponse struct {
    ErrorID int               `json:"error_id"`
    Msg     map[string]string `json:"message"`
}

func (c *ErrorResponse) Error() string {
    b, _ := json.Marshal(c)
    return string(b)
}
```

// and validate it on your code like :

```
if err := user.Validate(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
}
```

Comment: Yeah it's a model